# How to log out without having to confirm?

Tags: gnome, configuration

Whenever I log out from a Gnome session (by clicking on the "power" button in the top panel and choosing "Log out...", I have to answer the "Are you sure..." question.  How can I configure my system to avoid this question?

Since I already have performed two actions (clicking on the panel button, and selected the "Log out" item), it is quite probable that I actually *want* to log out. :)

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, being a list of actions "log out, switch user, restart, etc" it's not very hard to miss and accidentally select the wrong item, especially with a trackpad.

Comment: That's why I like the logout button on the panel. Especially since with several users there is lots of logging out, but almost no use of the other items in that menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following command

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/indicator-session/suppress_logout_restart_shutdown –t bool true
```

or open Configuration Editor and set it using the gui with below steps:

1. Press Alt+F2 and enter "gconf-editor"
2. Navigate to apps -> indicator-session
3. Check the box next to the name "suppress_logout_restart_shutdown" on the right hand side pane.
4. Exit Configuration editor.

More details can be found [here](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/losing-the-shutdown-confirmation-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic/).

Comment: For me the command there returns `Must specify a type when setting a value` (10.10)

Comment: There was an error in the gconftool-2 invocation (using -type instead of --type or -t). Strangely, we happen to encounter it only now... it could be because this key was already present in 10.04 and removed in 10.10. Can you try `gconftool-2 -g /apps/indicator-session/suppress_logout_restart_shutdown` and post the output on your system ? (For now I have edited the answer in anticipation of this)

Comment: It outputs `true` - but I had already changed the key using gconf-editor yesterday...

Comment: OK, until someone can verify on a vanilla 10.10 install, I will assume the error was in the wrong usage of the long option syntax, which I have fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way, but I always do the following.

Either in a terminal or by hitting ALT-F2 and entering run, start...
gconf-editor
select apps
select gnome-session
select options
uncheck logout_prompt

Then for each of my family members I right click on the panel
select Add To Panel
Add a logout button

Doesn't get any more convenient than that.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way is to use Ubuntu Tweak. No command-line. Just a simple checkbox.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what settings to set?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing Ctrl + Alt + Backspace? Works for me (GNOME classic without effects on Ubuntu 11.10).